# How can I join an array of strings but first remove the elements of the array that are empty?

Tags: c#, arrays, join, string

I am using the following:

```
return string.Join("\n", parts);
```

Parts has 7 entries but two of them are the empty string "".   How can I first remove these two entries and then join the remaining five?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `Where` in LINQ to select strings which are not empty:

```
 return string.Join("\n", parts.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)));
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternate way of doing this is by using StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries:

e.g.

```
string yourString = "The|quick||brown|||fox|is|here";
char[] delimiter = new char[] { '|' };

string result = string.Join(",", yourString.Split(delimiter, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

This gives:

> The,quick,brown,fox,is,here

@Stefan Steiger:

```
string yourString = "echo 'foo' | sed '/foo/d;'";
```

This gives:

> echo 'foo' , sed '/foo/d;'

Which is as I would expect. [See the dotnetfiddle of it](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9B4R9A).

Comment: Is `Values` a `string` like `"foo|bar||baz|||baf"`?

Comment: And now I enter a value like "echo 'foo' | sed '/foo/d;'" and it breaks horribly.

Answer (score 1):

Try it using `LINQ`

```
string[] hello = new string[] { "ads", "zxc", "wer", "", "wer", "", "243" };
string newString = string.Join("\n", hello.Where(x => x.Trim().Length != 0));
MessageBox.Show(newString);
```

or

```
return string.Join("\n", hello.Where(x => x.Trim().Length != 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it in .NET 2.0 (no LINQ), e.g. for ReportingServices without writing a function for it:

C#

```
string a = "", b = "b", c = "", d = "d", e = "";
string lala = string.Join(" / ",
    string.Join("\u0008", new string[] { a, b, c, d, e }).Split(new char[] { '\u0008' }, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
);

System.Console.WriteLine(lala);
```

VB.NET

```
Dim a As String = "", b As String = "b", c As String = "", d As String = "d", e As String = ""
Dim lala As String = String.Join(" / ", String.Join(vbBack, New String() {a, b, c, d, e}).Split(New Char() {ControlChars.Back}, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))

System.Console.WriteLine(lala)
```

This assumes that the character backspace doesn't occur in your strings (should usually be true, because you can't simply enter this character by keyboard).