# Convert array items to string on condition - Swift

Tags: arrays, string, swift

I am trying to create a file name from the URL. I have to forcefully remove the first item in the array every time. Like the C# [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12777650/how-can-i-join-an-array-of-strings-but-first-remove-the-elements-of-the-array-th) where they check for empty string.

Is it possible to remove the `"/"` in the array? Is there a better way to implement this?

```
let url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"
var filePathComponents:[String]  = []
filePathComponents = assetURL.pathComponents as! [String]
filePathComponents.removeAtIndex(0)
let fileName = "-".join(filePathComponents)
```

Comment: Removed the tag. Thank you

Comment: And the result you desire would be? "questions-ask"?

Comment: Yes that would be it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend

```
filePathComponents.filter { return $0 != "/" }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use mutability if you use range indexing (with `..<`).

And to make it convenient to use, let's put it in an extension as a computed property.

Example for String:

```
extension String {
    var pathNameWithoutPrefix: String {
        get {
            return "-".join(self.pathComponents[2 ..< self.pathComponents.count])
        }
    }
}

let filePath = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask".pathNameWithoutPrefix
println(filePath)  // "questions-ask"
```

Example for NSURL:

```
extension NSURL {
    var pathURLWithoutPrefix: NSURL? {
        get {
            if let filePathComponents = self.pathComponents as? [String] {
                return NSURL(string: "-".join(filePathComponents[1 ..< filePathComponents.count]))
            }
            return nil
        }
    }
}

if let url = NSURL(string: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"),
    let fileURL = url.pathURLWithoutPrefix {
    println(fileURL)  // "questions-ask"
}
```

*Here's the same extensions for Swift 2:*

```
extension String {
    var pathNameWithoutPrefix: String {
        get {
            let str = self as NSString
            return "-".join(str.pathComponents[2 ..< str.pathComponents.count])
        }
    }
}

extension NSURL {
    var pathURLWithoutPrefix: NSURL? {
        get {
            if let filePathComponents = self.pathComponents {
                return NSURL(string: "-".join(filePathComponents[1 ..< filePathComponents.count]))
            }
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let linkURL = NSURL(string: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask")!
if let comps = linkURL.pathComponents as? [String] {
    let fileName = "-".join(dropFirst(comps))   // "questions-ask"
}
```

**Swift 2.0**

```
let linkURL = NSURL(string: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask")!
if let comps = linkURL.pathComponents?.dropFirst() {
    let fileName = "-".join(comps)   // "questions-ask"
}
```

Comment: Is not the first path component 'questions'?  The stuff before that being <proto>://<host>:<port> I'd say?

Answer (score 0):

Different approach using the `host` and `path` properties of `NSURL`

```
if let assetURL = NSURL(string: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask") {
  let fileNameWithHost = assetURL.host!.stringByAppendingPathComponent(assetURL.path!) // "stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"
  let fileNameWithoutHost = assetURL.path!.substringFromIndex(assetURL.path!.startIndex.successor()) // "questions/ask"
}
```