# Count the filled array elements and display result into label

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, label

I've got a `string[] Brands = new string[10];`

With the following code i'm giving it 4 standard values. I can add values with a add button. (I already got this part of code)

```
public Form1()
        {
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                Merken[0] = "Yamaha";
                Merken[1] = "Suzuki";
                Merken[2] = "Harley";
                Merken[3] = "Kawasaki";
                merkNr = 4;
                listBoxMotoren.DataSource = Brands;

            }
        }
```

I want to display the FILLED elements of the array into a `label.text.

So, when I run the program the label shows the numer 4 (because 4 elements of the array are filled). When I add a value to the array with btnclick, the label needs to display the number 5 and so on...`

Comment: Anything you have tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I join an array of strings but first remove the elements of the array that are empty?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12777650/how-can-i-join-an-array-of-strings-but-first-remove-the-elements-of-the-array-th)

Comment: Yes, I already try to use the count.length method. But it displays the value 10. It just counts the POSSIBLE filled places in my array. I need to display only the values that are filled.

Comment: Why making your life harder, use `List<string>` instead

Comment: I can't use a list. It has to be a array (school project)

Comment: @Needsomehelp try following `Marken.Count(e => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e))`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Linq` to get count of filled elements from `array`.

```
int count = Merken.ToList().Where(x => (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))).Count();
yourLabel.Text = count.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you but as already stated, I can't use a list. is there a method just to count the filled elements of my array?

Comment: this is not a List it is an array. This is built in method of .Net Framework.

Comment: This method is applied to your `array` so you only need to write this line no need to create a l`ist`.

Comment: Dude, you are awesome. Thanx!

Comment: Just one little question. Could you please explain step by step what this code does?

int count = Merken.ToList().Where(x =>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))).Count();

Comment: This is linq. Actually this code checks in array how many elements have value and counts them. .`Where`  checks how many elements have value and `Count` gets number of those elements.

Comment: Thank you. And the (x => (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))) part?

Comment: This part checks every element of `array` if it is not an `empty string` or it is not `null`. `x` represents each element of `array`.

Answer (score 0):

Will you ever have blank indexes?

```
Merken[4] = ""
Merken[5] = "Honda"
```

If you are not going to ever have blank indexes, you can set your label to:

```
[arrayName].length
```

This will add together the number of indexes in the array.

EDIT: OP says there will be blank indexes

I would recommend looping through the array to see which indexes have values and then increment a counter which you will set as the label text.

```
int indexesWithValues = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < Brands.length; i++)
{
   if (Brands[i] != "")
   {
       indexesWithValues++;
   }
}
```

Then you set your label text to the counter.

Comment: Yes I will have blank indexes.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way would be to use a `List<string>` and display the `Count()` of the list. Lists are data structures which grow dynamically, thus each time you add an item to the list, the list grows automatically.

If you want to use arrays, you could start from the first element and use the `String.IsNullorEmpty(string str)` and a counter which is incremented each time you find a string which is neither null or empty.

Once that you hit a null/empty string, you stop your loop and display the counter.

Comment: Thank you but I can't use a list. It has to be a array.

Comment: @Needsomehelp: Then you will need to go for the second approach

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I'm interpreting this as more simple than it is, but as far as I can tell all you need to do is add "[name of label on form].Text = Merken.Count().ToString();" in the code that adds the new item.

Is there a particular reason you used Merken in the setup but declared it initially as Brands?

Answer (score 0):

why you arent using List
it has Count property. and if you need array for export you call .ToArray() method to get array of your list.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the number of elements in `array` using

```
Using System.LINQ  
-----

Marken.Count();
```

Comment: Thank you. But this displays the value 10. Not the actually filled elements.

Comment: try the edited answer .. But it is better to user `List<string>` in your case.